# How would I make my methods loop through an enum?

Tags: java, enums

I have an Environment enum and an Application enum. Each application also has its own class which has a test for that app. I want to run each test in all the environments before it goes on to the next test. Here is part of what I have in the main method

```
           for(Environment env :Environment.values())
            {
                new AccountInventory(env);
                AccountInventory.accountInventoryTests(null, env);

                new AuditActionItems( env);
                AuditActionItems.auditActionItemTests(null, env);

                new SalesPipeline(env);
                SalesPipeline.salesPipelineTests(null, env);
```

Here is an example of what I have in a class

```
public static boolean accountInventoryTests(Application app, Environment env)
{
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();


try{
driver.get(env.getDomain() + Application.ACCOUNTINVENTORY.getContextRoot());
driver.findElement(By.name("j_username")).sendKeys(USER);
driver.findElement(By.name("j_password")).sendKeys(PASSWORD);
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='submit']")).click();
```

Right now it runs all the tests in one environment, then runs all of them in the next environment. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve, can you please explain a little more?

Comment: Right now it runs all of the Application tests one environment at a time. I want it to run one Test in all four environments before it goes to the next test

Comment: Why don't you loop for each test?
`for(Environment env :Environment.values()) {...AccountInventory.accountInventoryTests(null, env);}`
`for(Environment env :Environment.values()) {...AuditActionItems.auditActionItemTests(null, env);}`

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like that you doesn't need to iterate your application-enum for your test, because you access them in your test-methods(see `Application.ACCOUNTINVENTORY.getContextRoot()`).

If you realy want to iterate your enum, you can try mabye this:

```
for(Environment env :Environment.values())
        {
            new AccountInventory(env);
            for(Application app: Application.values())
            {
              AccountInventory.accountInventoryTests(app, env);
            }

            new AuditActionItems( env);
            for(Application app: Application.values())
            {
              AuditActionItems.auditActionItemTests(app, env);
            }

            ...
        }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I think it almost helped, what your code did was infinitely loop over a single environment.